# Project structure in IntelliJ compared to Eclipse and Visual Studio?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, intellij-idea

I am coming from the .NET/Visual Studio world and have used Eclipse for a while. I am fairly new to IntelliJ and looking at its project structure I am wondering how it compares to the same in Visual Studio and Eclipse. If my understanding is correct:

IntelliJ Project = Eclipse Workspace = Visual Studio Solution

IntelliJ Module = Eclipse Project = Visual Studio Project

Is my understanding correct? I am asking because I have a Java Project which comprises of two fundamental parts. A backend data import processing (data-import-service) and a backend data report processing (report-processing-service), both should be Maven projects. And I am no sure how to organize these into IntelliJ.

1. Create two separate IntelliJ projects.
2. Create one IntelliJ Project with two separate modules.